# Java array in while loop

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop

So I'm wondering how we can create a while loop in which each element is initially set to 0. Then in the while loop there is a random number selection. Let's say the number is 5 for the first loop, then index 5 of the array nums with become 1. Lets say 5 is chosen again, then the index 5 in nums will become 2 etc. This loop needs to go on until the very last index = 1. So the only way to exit the loop is that each index in the nums array must be greater than or equal to 1.

I came up with the following loop but I know that it goes on infintely since the conditions in the while are wrong; but I can't come up with the right ones, Ive tried for a while... Help would be appreciated!

```
public class Question1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] nums =  new int [10];
    while ( nums[0]!=1 || nums[1]!=1 || nums[2]!=1 || nums[3]!=1 || nums[4]!=1 || nums[5]!=1 || nums[6]!=1 || nums[7]!=1 || nums[8]!=1 || nums[9]!=1){
        int i = rand.nextInt(10);
        nums[i]++;
}
```

Comment: You need `nums[whatever] < 1` or `nums[whatever] == 0`.

Comment: hahah thanks... what a simple solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random rand = new Random();
    int[] nums =  new int [10];

    while (stopTest(nums)){
        int i = rand.nextInt(10);
        nums[i]++;
    }
    //print to test
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));
}

private static boolean stopTest(int[] array) {

    for(int i: array) {
        if (i<1)    return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```